# Plot High and Low on Renko chart

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, tradingview-api

I'm trying to plot the daily Hi and Lows from a standard chart on top of a renko chart but it only shows up correctly on the last brick of the day and shows the previous days values for the rest of the bricks.

[picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8X2V.png)

Im using

```
reso = input.timeframe("D", 'Resolution')
smooth = input.int(1, 'Hi Lo Smoothing', 1, 1000, 1)

hi = request.security(ticker.standard(syminfo.tickerid),reso, high)
lo = request.security(ticker.standard(syminfo.tickerid),reso, low)

plot(ta.sma(hi, smooth), 'Hgh', color.purple)
```

I'm trying to plot the highs and lows for all the bricks in that day when they close on a daily chart.